# http response message

Tags: http, browser

I want to know that when browser sends a request do the server sends back the contents explicitly? And how would i confirm it?

Answer (score 2):

There are several toolbars in Firefox that show exactly what are coming and going when making an HTTP request.

For firefox i use the following plugins:

- Firebug
- Web Developer

You could also install a utility called WireShark. It will "sniff" all the network traffic on your computer and show you at a packet level how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

Browser plugins such as [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (for firefox) let you see exactly what the server is returning; that's quite instructive and recommended!  You'll see a bunch of headers followed by the response body in any of several formats (could be chunked, etc, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows environment you can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Fiddler includes a fair amount of documentation and is easy to use.